# Custom font works on storyboard but not on device and simulator?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am trying to use custom font (Roboto) in my iOS application. The steps I took are:

Copy the .ttf files to the project.
Confirm the .ttf files have set the project as target.
Added the .ttf files in 'Fonts provided by application' in plist.
In Build Phases, the .ttf files are in 'Copy Bundle Resources'.

Comment: check the font family.. Is your font is printing in console or not.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you done everything correctly.  I suggest you delete the app from test device and load it again.

As a side note with custom fonts, also think about how your font scales when used with scale font accessibility feature. 50% of people don't use default font sizes. System fonts (San Fran) has also scaling built in for it but for custom fonts you need to set that up manually.